# is it possible to get incoming call in air for android?

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, air

Does anyone know about get "incoming call event" in air for android?
is there ane resource or should I make it myself using TelephonyManager?
deactivate event is not suitable for me.

Comment: Do you mean "Adobe Air"? This question is not written clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phone on the Android device is in one of the [three states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged%28int,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
CALL_STATE_IDLE (when it is not engaged in any calls), 
CALL_STATE_RINGING (when there is an incoming call and device is ringing), 
CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK (when the user answers the call)
```

Even the EXTRA_STATE lookup key [TelephonyManager#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) used with the ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast correspond to these states as follows:

```
EXTRA_STATE_IDLE  (Value used with EXTRA_STATE corresponding to CALL_STATE_IDLE)
EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK (Value used with EXTRA_STATE corresponding to CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)
EXTRA_STATE_RINGING (Value used with EXTRA_STATE corresponding to CALL_STATE_RINGING)
```

So to answer your question, there is currently no event for a "incoming call in air" in Android.